# Tomcat WAR file which increments JSESSIONID on reload to test session replication

Tags: tomcat

I'm currently having to configure Tomcat for the first time.

For the moment, I think session replication (JSESSIONID) is working, but I have no way of knowing.

Note that I've never learned to code in Java and I don't plan to.

Here's what I want:

A **simple** `.war` file that prints the current JSESSIONID number and increments it everytime a webpage reloads.

Anyone knows where I can find this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified the code provided by @utrecht :

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class PageHitCounter extends HttpServlet{
/**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9119068346424522270L;
private String sessionId; 

  public void init() 
  {
     sessionId = "Not Set";
  } 

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
  {
      // Set response content type
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      // This method executes whenever the servlet is hit 
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

      String title = "JSESSIONID &and; count";
      HttpSession session = request.getSession();
      // Boolean isNew = session.isNew();
      sessionId = session.getId();

      Integer counter = (Integer)session.getAttribute("counter");
      if ( counter == null ){
          counter = new Integer(1);
      } else {
          counter = new Integer(counter.intValue() + 1);
      }
      session.setAttribute("counter", counter);
      String docType =
      "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 " +
      "transitional//en\">\n";
      out.println(docType +
        "<html>\n" +
        "<head><title>" + title + "</title></head>\n" +
        "<body bgcolor=\"#f0f0f0\">\n" +
        "<h1 align=\"center\">" + title + "</h1>\n" +
        "<h2 align=\"center\">" + sessionId + "</h2>\n" +
        "<h2 align=\"center\">" + counter + "</h2>\n" +
        "</body></html>");

  }
  public void destroy() 
  { 
      // This is optional step but if you like you
      // can write hitCount value in your database.
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Run Eclipse
2. CTRL+N (Dynamic Web Project) and name it **test**
3. Right click on the project > New > Servlet, enter
   **PageHitCounter** in the **Class name:** box > Next > Next, **unselect doPost** and Finish
4. Copy [this code](http://people.apache.org/~jim/NewArchitect/webrevu/1999/01_08/developers/01_08_99_3.html) and replace `// TODO Auto-generated method stub` comment which resides in the **doGet** method
5. Execute `CTRL+SHIFT+O` to import missing libraries and rename res and req to response and request respectively
6. Right click on the project and run it as `1 Run on Server`
7. If the expected page does not load, navigate to
   `http://localhost:8080/test/SessionTracker`
8. Reloading the webpage increments the number
9. If it works properly, right click on the project and `Export...` > `Web` > `WAR file`
10. Copy the war file to the webapps folder and restart tomcat

[image]

Java code if [link](http://people.apache.org/~jim/NewArchitect/webrevu/1999/01_08/developers/01_08_99_3.html) does not exist anymore:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet("/SessionTracker")
public class SessionTracker extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SessionTracker() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

        Integer count = (Integer) session.getValue("tracker.count");
        if (count == null)
            count = new Integer(1);
        else
            count = new Integer(count.intValue() + 1);
        session.putValue("tracker.count", count);

        out.println("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>SessionTracker</TITLE></HEAD>");
        out.println("<BODY><H1>Session Tracking Demo</H1>");

        out.println("You've visited this page " + count
                + ((count.intValue() == 1) ? " time." : " times."));

        out.println("<P>");

        out.println("<H2>Here is your session data:</H2>");
        String[] names = session.getValueNames();
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            out.println(names[i] + ": " + session.getValue(names[i]) + "<BR>");
        }
        out.println("</BODY></HTML>");
    }
}
```

Comment: I finally managed to compile it. Thank you! Very helpful.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work! This code doesn't use JSESSIONID at all. It just increments for anyone who hits the page. I want it to increment per-session. Otherwise I can't test Session replication.

Comment: @moebius_eye Ok. I will try to find a solution this evening.

Comment: @moebius_eye Could you update the question?

Comment: I've modified the code to suit my needs. I'll post it very soon.